# Printing data in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, wordpad

I have one problem about printing data in Mathematica. If the line so long for example

S=11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

I want to print S in form first five empty spaces, then to put "#" then 66 spaces of S,
then enter, next order again the same. This form must be in WordPad open like here

```
 "5 spaces empty"#1111111111"(66times)"111111
 "5 spaces empty"#1111111111"(66times)"111111
  .....
```

Best wishes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
In[58]:=
S=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111;
StringPartition[s_,l_]:=Table[StringTake[s,{i,Min[i+l-1, 
StringLength[s]]}],{i,1,StringLength[s],l}];
fmts=Map[("     #"<>#<>"\r")&,StringPartition[ToString[S],66]];
(* Unfortunately the web software is ruining the formatting of the output, deleting the extra spaces I placed before the #, etc. *)
(* But if you fix all the things this web software broke when I pasted your result and then run this and check the output carefully you should see it is correct *)
FullForm[fmts]

Out[61]//FullForm=
List[
"     #111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\r",
"     #111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\r",
"     #111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\r",
"     #111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\r",
"     #111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\r",
"     #11111111111111111111111111111111\r"
]
```

Comment: Thank you it is working. Just to check something little bit and I will write you.